# Media Push dont received on iOS because of ServiceExtension

Tags: apple-push-notifications, media, notification-service-extension

Service extension is added to the project, but it does not enter when debugging, what could be the problem?

I checked the deployment target and plist flie, while it works in a different project, it does not enter debug in the other one.